# plotBands Hide and Show parameters do not work in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I clicked in legend, the plotBands parameters `hide()` and `show()` do not work.

I wish I could click on the legend and remove a specific PlotBand.

I tried using destroy() but it cleans the html dom and I can't return with PlotBand when I click on the legend again.

I couldn't find how to remove and put the PlotBand back on:

```js
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 4,
    d = 5,
    dados = [[a, b, '#32CD32','manutenção','Mantuenção'], [c, d, '#FF0000','falha','Falha']];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',

        },
        showInLegend: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Zoom Geral e Barras Verticais'
        },
        yAxis: {
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true,
                showFull: false
            }
        },
            
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0,
            events:{
                legendItemClick:function(e){
                  
                  console.log(this.userOptions)

                  var ids = this.userOptions['id'];
                  console.log(ids)

                  if(this.userOptions['id'] === ids){
                    var hides = this.xAxis.plotLinesAndBands.filter(id => id.id == ids);
                    
                    if(this.visible == true){
                        hides[0].svgElem.hide()
                    } else {
                        hides[0].svgElem.show()
                      }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    },    
            
        series: [{
              name:'Série A',
            data: [-10, 31, 35, 40, 15, 10]  
        }
    ]
    },
    function(){
                    for (let i = 0; i < dados.length; i++ ){
          this.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
                   from: dados[i][0],
                   to: dados[i][1],
                   color: dados[i][2],
                   name: dados[i][4],
                   id: dados[i][3]

            }, )
            
          this.addSeries({
             marker: {
                        symbol: 'square',
                  radius: 20},
             name: dados[i][4],
             color: dados[i][2],
             type: 'scatter',
             id: dados[i][3]
            }, )
            }   
        }     
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot bands are not hidden because the chart is redrawn after the event. You can return false from the callback function, but all plot bands will be visible after another redraw. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m2xrjhLk/

I recommend you to remove/add the plot band on legend click:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            ...,
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(e) {
                    var id = this.options.id;

                    if (this.visible) {
                        this.xAxis.removePlotBand(id);
                    } else {
                        this.xAxis.addPlotBand(plotBands.find(
                            plotBand => plotBand.id === id
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1jgew27/

Comment: Nice solution. I understand what you said. I will pay attention to this. Thank you!! :-) I keep track of your resolutions on highcharts. They are excellent. Congratulations.  Sorry for my English. rsrs

Comment: There is a problem. When I click on the series legend, I get an error. The Series does not return. :-(

Comment: Hi @VINICIUS BODART, Could you reproduce the error in jsfiddle? Everything seems to work fine in my example.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. In your exemple (http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1jgew27/) when I click in legend appears error. 
In legend we have three "options" (1 series and 2 plotbands). When I clicked in options by plotbands works fine, but doens't work when click in series ("Série A"). There's error in this moment, to return the series.

Comment: Thanks for the explonation! You are right, we need to add an additional check. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5pamswu6/